# Component as Pop up Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am creating a `Pop up`

```
  this.popUp = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    closeButton: true,
    closeOnClick: true,
    anchor: 'bottom-left',
  })
    .setLngLat(coordinates)
    .setHTML(
      '<span><p>Foo: Bar
      + <img class="pop-up-image" src=.../></span>'
    )
    .addTo(this.map);
```

The content of the `Pop up` I define the following

```
.setHTML(
      '<span><p>Foo: Bar
      + <img class="pop-up-image" src=.../></span>'
    )
```

Is there a way to pass a `React.Component` or a `functional Component` to the Pop up as content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If possible, I'd go with [React wrapper for mapbox-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl). According to the [popup docs](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/blob/master/docs/components/popup.md) you can add any React component as `Popup` child. Otherwise the answer to your question would be [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916901/possible-to-render-react-component-within-mapboxgl-popup-in-sethtml-or-setdo), I believe

EDIT:

You may do it also in this way:

```
const placeholder = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(el, placeholder);

new mapboxgl.Popup({
  closeButton: true,
  closeOnClick: true,
  anchor: 'bottom-left',
})
.setLngLat(coordinates)
.setDOMContent(placeholder)
.addTo(this.map);
```

This should do the trick, hopefully.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to maintain functionality of onClicks and other non-HTML aspects of the component you're hoping to render, Adam's suggestion will allow for that, vs some other posts suggesting the use of ReactDOMServer.renderToString(), which only outputs the HTML.